# Why is my sidebar not filling to the edge of my border?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a right floated sidebar in a parent div, with a different background color. The parent has a 3px dashed border, and the sidebar doesn't extend all the way to the edges. Instead, the parent's background color is visible between the dashes.

[a view of the body of the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJGiM.png)

[a closer view of the corner, showing that the background does not meet the edge of the border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92TYI.png)

I've tried adjusting the positions, changing the order of my elements, changing the height and width, I'm kind of at a loss.

```css
body {
    background-image: url("https://i.lensdump.com/i/Rxu5rz.png");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Smalle';
    src: url("https://files.catbox.moe/x368w4.ttf");
}

.main {
    position: absolute;
    width: 650px;
    height: 675px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -325px;
    margin-left: -350px;
    
    border: 3px dashed #456655;
    background-color: #fff8e5;
    font-family: 'Smalle';
    
}

.sidebar {
    position: relative;
    height: 675px;
    width: 200px;
    float: right;
    
    background-color: #FEDA6A;
    
    
}

.sidecontent {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Smalle';
}

.content {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>TITLE</title>
        <link href="1styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <style>
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="sidebar">
                <br>
                <div class="sidecontent">
                    <p>This is where text and links will go... eventually.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <center><span class="title">TITLE</span></center>
                <p style="padding: 5px; margin: 6px; width: 425px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: well the child is inside of the parent and the parent has the border and background.

Comment: Why not add the border to the two elements inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this with flexbox. Put outline on the parent and use negative margins to move the child to cover up the outline.

```css
.page-wrapper {
  margin: 15px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  outline: 5px dashed green;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: stretch; 
  background-color: red;
  margin: -5px;
  padding: 10px;
}


.column.left {
  border-right: 0px;
}

.column.right {
  border-left: 0px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class='page-wrapper'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='column left'>
      Column 1
    </div>
    <div class='column right'>
      Column Two
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, is this what you want to achieve?

```css
body {
    background-image: url("https://i.lensdump.com/i/Rxu5rz.png");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Smalle';
    src: url("https://files.catbox.moe/x368w4.ttf");
}

.main {
    position: absolute;
    width: 650px;
    height: 675px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -325px;
    margin-left: -350px;
    border: 3px dashed #456655;
    background-color: #fff8e5;
    font-family: 'Smalle';
    
}

.sidebar {
   position: relative;
   height: 681px;
   width: 200px;
   float: right;
   background-color: #FEDA6A;
   top: -3px;
  right: -3px;
}
    

.sidecontent {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Smalle';
}

.content {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>TITLE</title>
        <link href="1styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <style>
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="sidebar">
                <br>
                <div class="sidecontent">
                    <p>This is where text and links will go... eventually.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <center><span class="title">TITLE</span></center>
                <p style="padding: 5px; margin: 6px; width: 425px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```